# Is there a bug causing Emperor Palpatine mission to not register?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have a mission stating to "Have 5 Bitizen(s) move in". I have built 2 residential levels, the first one I allowed the slots to fill in gradually/naturally. Once all five bitizens moved in I checked the mission and it didn't register as finished. The second residential level I had used one of my saved VIP's (the Recruiting officer) and filled up the lvl instantly but to no avail. The mission is still not recognizing at finished and requires 5 Bux to skip, which I really do not want to use up if at all possible.

Does anyone know why this is happening and if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: I had similar problem with 30 Bitizen(s) mission, after update this mission was silently repleaced with 5 Bitizen(s), and eventually was finished.

Comment: I tagged this as 'tiny-death-star'. If this is not the correct game in question, please update the tag to the correct one.

Comment: @WiccanMutti did you build the Residential levels before or after the mission began?

Comment: @ColinD Thank you, I thought that I had tagged it but I guess not.
 And at Turtleweezard I built the residential levels after the mission came up. :(

Answer (score 1):

There have been numerous reports of the Emperor's missions not registering.  Most seem to have resolved themselves after waiting for a period of time.

In any case, the Emperor's missions are not critical to completion of the game, and the payout is not very good for them.  So, continue playing the game, and if it resolves, great.  If not, it should not hamper your enjoyment of the game.

The Emperor's missions are merely a guide for playing the game, but if you choose to disregard the missions, you can build any levels you like.

UPDATE:  I had the same mission just today.  And, while I'm certain I had 5 more more bitizen move in here and there, I did not receive the credit until using a recruiting agent and having 5 move in on a new residential floor.

Comment: Imperial missions have far better payouts. I focus on those.

Comment: Well at least it is good to know that it's not critical to the continuing of the game. I would just like for it to change, mainly for my gaming OCD. lol I just wanted to make sure before I get too terribly far into it in case I needed to reinstall it.  

Thank you all for the input it has been very appreciated.

Comment: I hear you about the OCD. It bothers me when I can't complete something like that. But, hopefully it will be fixed in an update.